# Make facebook like point to blog post url?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-like, blogs

I´m adding facebook like buttons to my wordpress-page. On single.php, for each blog post - which works fine. But I would also like to add facebook like button to the posts on the index page. I could do that, but the url retrieved is the main index page, which makes sense. Is there a way I can have multiple like buttons on my blog main page, and still make each one of them to point to the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you set the `href` parameter for each individual like button to the post permalink. It's the `data-href` attribute in the HTML version:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://example.com/your-blog-post" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the index page and inside "[The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)", you could use the `the_permalink()` function as your Like button `href`.